# thrust::exclusive_scan_by_key unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

```
int data[ 10 ] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
int keys[ 10 ] = { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 };
thrust::exclusive_scan_by_key( keys, keys + 10, data, data );
```

By the examples at [Thrust Site](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__segmentedprefixsums.html) I expected `0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4`, but got `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0` instead; Is it bug, or is there somewhere something the defines this behavior?

More importantly, assuming this is not a bug, is there a way to achieve this effect easily?

Comment: The snippet works on my system (CUDA 7.0, release candidate). How are you printing the values of `data`? Also, the title does not match with the Thrust primive considered in the body.

Comment: @JackOLantern By works you mean works as expected and not just ten `0`? There are problems here, I guess I still have CUDA 6.5. I am printing by looping though them with `for ( int i =0 ; i < 10 ; ++i ) printf( "%d, ", data[ i ] );`?

Comment: Works with the result at the Thrust site you linked to, that is, the correct result.

Comment: @JackOLantern It could help if you can provide a bit more information. When you say 'correct result' you mean what I thought is bug (`0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0`) or what I expected (`0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you understand what scan_by_key does.  From the [documentation](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__segmentedprefixsums.html#ga115ffd69c3e45736772cbdf2b74b9097):

> "Specifically, consecutive iterators i and i+1 in the range [first1, last1) belong to the same segment if binary_pred(*i, *(i+1)) is true, and belong to different segments otherwise"

scan_by_key requires that your key array mark distinct segments using contiguous values:

```
keys: 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
seg#: 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

thrust compares *adjacent* keys to determine segments.

Your keys are producing a segment map like this:

```
int keys[ 10 ] = { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 };
          seg#:    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

Since you are doing an exclusive scan, the correct answer to such a segment map (regardless of the data) would be all zeroes.

It's not entirely clear what "this effect" is that you want to achieve, but you may want to do back-to-back stable sort by key operations, reversing the sense of keys and values, to rearrange this data to group the segments (i.e. keys 1 and 2) together.

Comment: I knew of the stable sort by key method, hence I added 'easily' in that sentence.